# ORA-00979 not a Group By function error

Tags: oracle, ora-00979

Iam trying to select 2 values from a Table, Employee emp_name, emp_location grouping by emp_location, iam aware that the columns which are in group by function needs to be in select clause, but i would like to know whether is there any other way to get these value in a single query.

My intention is to select only one employee per location based on age.
sample query

```
select emp_name,emp_location 
from Employee 
where emp_age=25 
group by emp_location
```

please help in this regard.

Thanks a lot for all the guys who have responded for this question. I will try to learn these windows functions as these are very handy.

Comment: `group by emp_location.` Dot what?

Comment: "*based on age*" - there is no age column nor a date of birth column in your example

Comment: Iam sorry, the query is "select emp_name,emp_location 
from Employee 
where emp_age=25 
group by emp_location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this works in MySQL and not in Oracle, is because in Oracle, as well most other databases, you either need to specify a field (or expression) in the `group by` clause, or it has to be an aggregation which combines the values of all values in the group into a single one. For instance, this would work:

```
select max(emp_name),emp_location 
from Employee 
where emp_age=25 
group by emp_location
```

However, it's may not the best solution. It will work if you want just the name, but you'll get into trouble when you want to have multiple fields for an employee. In that case `max` won't do the trick. In the query below, you might get a first name that doesn't match the last name.

```
select max(emp_firstname), max(emp_lastname), emp_location 
from Employee 
where emp_age=25 
group by emp_location
```

On solution for this, is using a window function (analytical function). With those, you can generate a value for each record, without immediately reducing the number of records. For instance, with a windowed `max` function, you could select the max age for people named `John`, and display that value next to every John in the result, even if they don't have that age.

Some functions, like `rank`, `dense_rank` and `row_number` can be used to generate a number for each employee, which you can then use to filter by. In the example below, I created such a counter per location (partition by), and ordered by, in this case name and id. You can specify other fields as well, for instance if you want one name per age per location, you specify both age and location in `partition by`. If you want the oldest employee of each location, you can remove `where emp_age=25` and `order by emp_age desc` instead.

```
select
  *
from
  (select 
    emp_name, emp_location,
    dense_rank() over (partition by emp_location order by emp_name, emp_id) as emp_rank
  from Employee 
  where emp_age=25)
where
  emp_rank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GolezTrol. The windows function worked as a charm and able to get all the desired values from the query. Many thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

> ORA-00979 not a Group By function error

Only aggregate functions *and* columns specified in the `GROUP BY` clause are allowed in the `SELECT` clause.

In that regard, Oracle follows the SQL standard closely. But, as you noticed in your comment, some other RDBMS are less strict than Oracle regarding that point. For example, to quote [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) (emphasis mine):

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. [...]
>
> **However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.** The server is free to choose any value from each group, so **unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate**.

So, in the recommended use case, adding the extra columns to the `GROUP BY` clause will lead to the same result.

---

```
select emp_name,emp_location 
--     ^^^^^^^^
--   this is *not* part of the ̀`GROUP BY` clause
from Employee 
where emp_state=25 
group by emp_location
```

*Maybe* are you looking for:

```
...
group by emp_location, emp_name
```

Comment: No the existing application was working with mysql database, so there was no problem now we are migrating to oracle so we are facing issue with this query.

Comment: That's because MySQL is silly and basically selects one random name in your situation.

Comment: @sriramdev MySQL supports that "feature" as an extension. See my edit if you need more insights.

Answer (score 0):

```
select emp_name,emp_location
from Employee
where emp_age=25
group by emp_name,emp_location
```

or

```
select max(emp_name) emp_name,emp_location
from Employee
where emp_age=25
group by emp_location
```

Comment: I think `max(emp_name)` is not very useful when you group by  `emp_name`.

Comment: It's group by *emp_location* . That's not best solution, but at least that is what @sriramdev got in mysql.

Comment: I thought it said `emp_name`. Anyway, as it is now, the second query won't work because `emp_name` is still in the select in non-aggregated form.

Comment: _" at least that is what [@]sriramdev got in mysql"_ Not necessary. MySQL is free to choose _any_ value if the values are not the same in the group. I'm wouldn't even assume it will return the _same_ value each time -- as I cannot find any such guarantee in the documentation. Or do I missed it ?